# Get the count of files that contain a string in their names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've created a [custom submenu](https://superuser.com/questions/1242099/create-a-new-new-submenu-in-context-menu-with-a-custom-name) in the Context Menu and I update it as I came across problems.

The way it works is that I have template files. Whenever I click on an item (file type) on the submenu, that template file is copied to the current folder and renamed. For example:

```
@echo off
copy C:\Windows\CustomNew\templates\html.html "%cd%"
rename html.html "New HTML Document.html"
```

The problem with this code is that if I create two HTML files, first one is renamed, but the second one is not. And that's because there's already a file with the name `"New HTML Document.html"` in the current folder. So it just stays as `"html.html"`. To get around this, I tried:

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

copy C:\Windows\CustomNew\templates\html.html "%cd%"

set name="New HTML Document.html"

if exist %name% (
    set name="New HTML Document (2).html"
)

rename html.html !name!
```

This works, but what if I wanted to create more than two files? I still have the initial problem. To fix that, I need to get the count of files that contains `"New HTML Document"` in their names, add 1 to it, and rename the new file accordingly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

implement a counter and a loop:

```
@ECHO OFF
break>html.html
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "name=New HTML Document.html"
set count=0

:loop
if not exist "%name%" goto :continue
set /a count+=1
set "name=New HTML Document (%count%).html"
goto :loop

:continue
rename html.html "%name%"
dir new*
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Using `"name=New HTML Document.html"` was causing this error. So I changed it to `name="New HTML Document.html"` and it worked.

Comment: My code works (note the different places where `"%name%"` is used (quoted)). `set "var=value"` is the preferred syntax. Take care of the quotes, where they are needed (`ren ... "%var%"`), don't include them into the variable. ("preferred" doesn't mean "mandatory", so your code works too, but try to get used to the preferred syntax to avoid several possible failures)

Comment: Yes, I've looked it (`set "var=value"`) up. But I was still getting an error. I guess that was because I was using both `%` and `!`. Now, I've set everything with `set "var=value"` and it's working.